# Tensorflow `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tuples, dataset

When I run this code for generating the dataset and training a GAN,

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 128
img_width = 128

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

autoencoder.fit(train, train,
                epochs=10,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=val)
```

It returns this error

```
`y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

From what I've seen I need to make the input a tuple but I'm not sure of how to do that and I can't find anything that shows me how.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) auto generate labels for the image based on your directory structure, and returns tuples of `(images, labels)`. That's why [`fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) does not accept `y` argument as labels should come directly from the `dataset`.

If you want to manually specify labels for your dataset, pass it as the argument `labels` when calling `image_dataset_from_directory`. Note that

> Labels should be sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the image file paths (obtained via `os.walk(directory)` in Python).